# nginx organise node js sites in directories

Tags: nginx, node.js

I'm running multiple NodeJS sites on a DigitalOcean VPS and would like to organise the sites into folders labelled by their domain eg busstopcards.co.uk.  Unfortunately my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default isn't working, the domain isn't resolving to the node app

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name busstopcards.co.uk;
    root /home/user;
    location /busstopcards.co.uk  {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
}
```

Please can someone suggest a solutions
Thanks
David

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial use of nginx. Have you read any documentations, tutorials, or a quick start? [Nginx beginners guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html). [My nginx tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/), which covers a lot of basics.

You need to create a symbolic link from sites-enabled to sites-available.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name busstopcards.co.uk;
  root /var/www/busstopcards;
  location /  {
    # Whatever
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /var/www/example.com;
  location /  {
    # Whatever
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you @Tim , actually I found this tutorial most use [Nginx Server Blocks](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

Comment: Yep Digital Ocean have some great information